# Retrieve picture from DB to the Details View in MVC

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have images(VARBINARY(MAX)) stored in my DB as shown below:
[image]

I have a controller to get bytes from the DB and display pictures, here is the controller code:

```
using SozlukRG.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SozlukRG.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            List<Kelime> kelime;
            kelime = null;
            return View(kelime);
        }
        public FileContentResult Show(int id)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            Resim kelime = db.Resim.Find(id);
            var imagedata = kelime.Adi;

            return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            List<Kelime> Kelime;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                Kelime = db.Kelime.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                Kelime = db.Kelime
                    .Where(s => s.Kelime1.StartsWith(searchTerm)).ToList();
            }
            return View(Kelime);

        }
        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);

            if (kelime == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(kelime);
        }


        public JsonResult GetKelime(string term)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            List<string> Kelime = db.Kelime.Where(s => s.Kelime1.StartsWith(term))
                .Select(x => x.Kelime1).ToList();
            return Json(Kelime, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my details view, not displaying the pictures:

```
@model SozlukRG.Models.KelimeTuru

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


<fieldset>
    <p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
    <legend>KelimeTuru</legend>
    <div class="div1" style="display: table; background-color: #b0c4de;">
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">

                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KelimeId)
            </div>





            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VideoId)
            </div>


            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ResimId)
            </div>




            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Anlam)
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KelimeId)
                </div>
                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="/Videos/b.mp4" type="video/mp4">

                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    <img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "image", new { id = Model.Id } ) %>'>
                    **@* Here I am supposed to see the picture with the called id, but I can't*@**
                    </div>


                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Anlam)
                </div>

        </div>
        </div>

</fieldset>
<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</p>
```

*If I create a View called Resim as and type localhost:52278/Home/show/2 in the address bar, it works just fine.*
However I'd like to see the pictures when I call the details view like :
localhost:52278/Home/details/3
**Could anybody help me show my pics within the details view?**
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Er, the problem was that you were trying to use aspx markup `<%= %>` in a Razor `@` view... Neither of the answers address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to define an action which render an imageResult instead of actionResult and in your html put the url of that action on src attribute of img (with query-string required probably)

```
    <img src='/Resim/Show/@Model.Id'>
```

Comment: You were right friend, but a small change was needed:
<img src='/Resim/Show/@Model.Id'>

Answer (score 1):

As you have the Show action in the same controller you do not need the name of the controller. Please do let us know what is the error why are getting ? Id is not correct or any exception you are getting.

```
          Url.Action( "show", new { id = Model.Id } )
```

Comment: I typed it as : <img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "Resim", new { id = Model.Id } ) %>'> Still not displaying ..

Comment: Can you see the Url in the source code...and share it. Type the same in the browser and see if it is coming. You can also run the developer tool of IE F12 to see what is the request is being made by the page and what is the response.

Comment: This url retrieves the pic: http://localhost:52278/Home/show/2
But I want this to retrieve it too: http://localhost:52278/Home/details/2

Comment: Can you share your controller and actions method . I am not sure why you have issue if the image is server from other controller.

Comment: I edited my question and put all the actions up there, hope it helps

Comment: I updated my answer. Please add what kind of error you are facing.

Comment: Here is the error in google chrome console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Can you share the URL it is trying to retrieve the image ?

Comment: While it's supposed the retrieve the picture within url: http://localhost:52278/Home/show/2
It tries to retrieve with this: http://localhost:52278/Home/Details/%3C%=%20Url.Action(%20%22show%22,%20new%20%7B%20id%20=%20Model.Id%20%7D%20)%20%%3E